# Problem with Structure inside structure in C

Tags: c

I have this code :

```
struct node{
   double *coordinates; 
};

struct vptree{
   struct node vp;
   double md;
   int idx;
   struct vptree *inner;
   struct vptree *outer;
};

void buildvp(double *X, int n, int d){

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<d;j++){
        printf("%lf   ",X[i*d+j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   struct vptree *tree;
   printf("That 's ok! 1\n");
   tree->vp.coordinates=(double *)malloc(d*sizeof(double));
   printf("That 's ok! 2\n");

   for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
      tree->vp.coordinates[i]=X[(n-1)*d+i];
      printf("for i=%d the X= %lf",i,tree->vp.coordinates[i]);  
   }
}


int main(){
   double X[8][2]={{2,5},{1,1},{0,0},{1,3},{2,5},{1,1},{-2,8},{6,-1}};
   buildvp(&X,8,2);
   return 0;
}
```

When the matrix X is 7x2 or 5x2, the program it's ok. When the matrix X is 8x2 or 6x2 the program doesn't print the message "That's ok 2". I realize something is wrong with the structure(specifically in the command 
`tree->vp.coordinates=(double *)malloc(d*sizeof(double))`) but I cannot fix it. Do you have any ideas;

Comment: Don't cast the returned pointer from malloc in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   struct vptree *tree;
   printf("That 's ok! 1\n");
   tree->vp.coordinates=(double *)malloc(d*sizeof(double));
```

`tree` is not pointing to valid memory that is the reason you have undefined behavior when you dereference it.

Maybe you first need to allocate memory to it and `free` it later.

```
   struct vptree *tree = malloc(sizeof *tree);
     …
   free(tree);
```

or declare it as normal variable.

```
   struct vptree tree;
   // access it using (.) operator
   tree.vp.coordinates=(double *)malloc(d*sizeof(double));
```